# Home electric circuit goes dead without tripping breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a 15 amp circuit in my home with 8 outlets.  Every couple of months it mysteriously stops working, however, the breaker doesn’t trip.  After a couple days I re-apply the breaker and all is good.   Is this dangerous?  A breaker problem?  Have mice eaten the wires?

Comment: If the entire circuit is going out, this suggests that something before the first receptacle is bad. This would be the connection at the first receptacle or the breaker. Is it the case that when it happens that all of the receptacles are off. Changing a breaker is simple and inexpensive. Have you ever had any experience in doing this? If not, call an electrician. Check the connections on the first receptacle from the panel. Insulation burned? Are the connections made with backstabs of the spring loaded type? If so, change them to the side screws.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest changing any parts until all connections are carefully checked.

Answer (score -1):

I would be verifying that all 8 outlets are not working, this is quite common with backstab outlets that are daisy chained. The problem is usually found at the first non working outlet or the last working outlet. This failure is much more common than a circuit breaker failure. The open circuit condition can be on the black or white wire, if it starts working after pulling the outlet and back stabs were used the outlet should be at a minimum rewired to the screw terminals or replace the outlet with a spec grade 4$ vs a .98$ outlet , but verify the working / non working outlets. 
There is a slight possibility of a bad panel with FPR or federal pacific stab lock breakers or a zinsco these are known to have issues and are beyond the average home owner repair, verify all the outlets first next time it goes out.

Comment: You do not need spec grade outlets. You could by all new ones at .98 and be fine .Sure they are better if you want.